# Is there a function in Python to show all rows from a particular year from a data frame with a column of Date type?

Tags: python, pandas

`df['Date']`

gives me the data like this

```
2014-08-22
2016-08-27
2014-04-12
2015-05-05
```

I need a way to filter out so that it returns only the entire rows from the year 2014.

the type of df['Date'] is pandas.core.series.Series

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df = df[df['Date'].dt.year == 2014]
```

For multiple years:

```
df = df[df['Date'].dt.year.isin([2014, 2015])]
```

Comment: Oh thanks, that works, what if I want to use two years (2015, 2015)?

Comment: @AasemJS - answer was edited.